# Remove queryKey from hashHistory react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I've found several places that say to set `queryKey: false`, but I can't find where to set that with the specific packages I'm using. Here's my current setup:

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import createStore from './store/createStore'

const store = createStore(initialState, hashHistory)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**example with { queryKey: false }**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import reducers from '<project-path>/reducers'

import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
import { Router, Route, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'

import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer,routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'


// Apply the middleware to the store
const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reducers,
      routing: routerReducer
  }),
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(reduxRouterMiddleware)
)
//set { queryKey: false }
const appHashHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })

// Create an enhanced history that syncs navigation events with the store
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(appHashHistory, store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="foo" component={Foo}/>
        <Route path="bar" component={Bar}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('mount')
)
```